# Get ViewController from Appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have four views in my storyboard

1. ViewOne
2. ViewTwo
3. ViewThree
4. ViewFour

In my `ViewTwo`, I make a call and open an new App and when the URL opening is done I call the following function in my `Appdelegate`

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
```

What I do here is that I iterate through all my viewControllers because I want to find my `ViewTwo` to be able to call a segue that I have created. I want to do it this way because I don´t want to create a new instance of the viewController.

It works great with this function below to find `ViewTwo`:

```
if let viewControllers = window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers {
    for viewController in viewControllers {
        if viewController.isKindOfClass(ViewTwo) {
            viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("sw", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

But now I have added a `NavigationController` to `ViewTwo`, `ViewThree` and `ViewFour` so when I run the snippet above I only get the following result for viewController (I made a simple `print(viewController)`)

```
<ViewOne: 0x...>
<UINavigationController: 0x...>
<UINavigationController: 0x...>
<UINavigationController: 0x...>
```

**So my question is, how do I check for ViewTwo now that I also have a NavigationController?**

Comment: You may be able to use the topViewController property on the navigation controller instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewThree") as! WebViewController
self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the view controller from storyboard without creating a new instance. You don't need to iterate through all the view controllers. Also why do you not set the view controller as the root of your nav controller instead of performing a segue?

You can get the view controller from storyboard like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewTwo") as! ViewTwoViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

Because now you are all getting `UINavigationViewController`. And it's just simply a controller of controller. You can access the root view controller from `UINavigationViewController` by accessing the first element of `viewControllers` property. Then, you are able to make the interpolation.

> The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view
>   controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1,
>   where n is the number of items in the array.